# How can I prevent deleting picklist value that is in use?

Tags: picklist

I have created a picklist field, and added some values in it.

I than discovered that I can delete the values from the lead->setup page, and this will remove the value from all selections/filters etc.

**It WILL** leave any object that has the old/deleted value in place, but I can't filter it from the smart filter boxes.

Q: How can I prevent that from happening? How can I ensure that such values will NOT be deleted, or at least be replaced with other valid values?

I am pretty sure this is how it works with LeadSource field - I want the same behaviour

Answer (score 2):

You can't prevent deletion of a picklist value, but you can use the replace functionality to update picklist values to new values.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Any value can be entered into a picklist as a text entry. That's the normal behavior for picklists. Unless you overwrite a stored value on an existing record when performing an update operation, you should have no problems with existing values being changed on a record without your having explicitly called for it to be a changed to a new value.

Comment: I know you can enter any text, but once you do, you can't select the new values in filters (you can enter it manually) I want ONLY valid fields.

Comment: So your issue is you still want to select it even after it's no longer a valid picklist choice? That wasn't apparent at the time I replied to your post. It appeared you were primarily concerned that a previous/no-longer-current value would be overwritten which isn't the case without an explicit update operation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a validation rule can help here, you can check for picklist value in required valid set of values.

Something like:

`NOT (OR (ISBLANK(YourPickListField__c), ISPICKVAL(YourPickListField__c, "Val1"),ISPICKVAL(YourPickListField__c, "Val2"), ...  ISPICKVAL(YourPickListField__c, "ValN"))`

Comment: must be better method than this.

Comment: Yeah, I am also looking for the same, let see what comes out.